# Downsides of a Magnetosphere stronger that Earth's?

Tags: science-based, planets, space-colonization, electromagnetism

It is clear that a planet that possesses a weaker magnetosphere than that of the Earth will present issues (such as less protection from stellar radiation) to a potential human colony. However, are there any issues that would arise when the planet has a magnetosphere that is stronger than the Earth's?

Comment: I'm not sure that a stronger magnetosphere per-se has a downside, but what causes the stronger magnetosphere could very much have a downside.  Are you specifically looking at only the downside of a stronger magnetosphere (fewer aurora borealis), or are you also entertaining the downside of their causes (higher gravity...)?

Comment: @JBH I am asking more about the direct effects of a stronger magnetic field. I don't know whether it would effect surface to orbit communications, or the intensity of the planet's Van Allen belts for instance.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18557/what-would-the-effects-be-on-a-earth-like-planet-if-the-magnetic-field-was-much

Answered here.

Comment: OK.  Please edit your question to indicate that you are not interested at this time in the negative effects of what might cause a stronger magnetosphere.  We don't want answerers to get sidetracked onto issues that aren't of interest to you. 

Comment: Aw, crud.  Sorry, Arkenstein.  It's a duplciate.

Comment: That answer doesn't mention... it could affect pacemakers.

Comment: I must have used the wrong search terms when I looked for it!